# Filter Array of Arrays in F#

Tags: multidimensional-array, filter, f#

I'm new on F#. I need to filter an Array of Arrays of strings, and I do not know how can this be done.
I need to be able to search if a certain row has a value, and filter acording to this.

I'm not allowed to use any type of "For or While". I've been looking for things like Array.Filter, Sort, Find, but i dont know how can you use those when you have an Array of Arrays.

Please help, i've been trying to solve this for like 10 days already

Here is a picture of the Array format, and I want for example to be able to filter and take out the rows that contains "f"

http://es.tinypic.com/r/2133nzp/8

Comment: What do you mean you're "not allowed"?  And what exactly are you trying to do (for example, what's the output you're looking for)?

Comment: Why doesn't `Array.filter` work?

Comment: Could you add example input and output of what you want?

Comment: Im uploading a picture of the array. i mean that im not allowed to use them because we are focusing on Funcional language, and they want us to use recursive methods and Filters, sort, etc.
Thanks!

Comment: So what part of using Array.filter are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't know how to write/use this for an Array of Arrays. There's where i'm stuck on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the chain of comments above is getting painfully long I'll try offering you a prompt.

You should begin with understanding of the definition of [F# Array.filter<'T> function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353840.aspx). The signature

> Array.filter : ('T -> bool) -> 'T [] -> 'T []

reads in plain, though an accurate language as: "if you have an array of elements of generic type **'T** (**'T [ ]** in the signature), and another function **p** defined on type **'T** that given an element of type **'T** returns **true** if the element has desired properties and **false** otherwise (**('T -> bool)** in the signature), then applying **Array.filter** to some array **aIn** of type **'T [ ]** will yield the other array **aOut** of same type **'T [ ]** containing only those elements of **aIn** on which **p**, being applied to each, yields **true**". In order to really grasp this it may help playing thru F# interpreter an example: let's our **'T** is an array of integers, so **'T []** is *array of arrays of integers*, and **aIn** below is an example of such array containing three different arrays of integers:

```
let aIn = [| [|1|]; [|-1;2;1|]; [|0;5|]; |]
```

Then, let's our predicate **p** means "an array of integers given as argument *does not* contain negative numbers", which may be expressed in "wordy manner" in F# as

```
let p (arg: int[]) = arg |> Array.exists (fun x -> x < 0) |> not
```

Make sure you fully understand what **p**, **arg**, **x**, and **(fun x -> x < 0)** above mean, in particular, that **x** there is a plain single integer.

Finally, let's combine these bits and pieces together following the original **Array.filter** signature:

```
let aOut = Array.filter p aIn
```

Entering three above lines of code into F# interpreter you should end up with

```
val aOut : int [] [] = [|[|1|]; [|0; 5|]|]
```

which is a copy of **aIn**, but missing the middle array element **[|-1;2;1|]** containing a negative element.

Given you grasp the above it should not be difficult for you now to solve your original problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it worked!!!! Just a short question, if i want to use this to string [][] list ??

Comment: @DanielFleiderman: NP. As to your question - switching to `string[][] list` does not change the approach, just filtering applies to **list of arrays of arrays of string**, and its predicate - to **array of arrays of string**. Like `List.filter (fun x -> (Array.length x) > 1)` filters out arrays of arrays of string having less, than two arrays of strings.